# How to print a Word document as a coversheet?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to add a Word document cover sheet to a quote I am printing from Excel.

This is what I have tried, but I can see that it is flawed in trying to use objects in an Array.

I want to print the current selection of the Excel sheet, with the Word document as a cover sheet, into one PDF file.

```
Sub PrintQuoteCover()

Set WordApp = Nothing 'release the memory

    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim CSELECT As Range

    Set CSELECT = Selection
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("O:\12.Product Info\QUOTE COVER MARKETING.docx")

    Dim ARRAYONE As Variant
    ARRAYONE = Array(objDoc, CSELECT)
    ARRAYONE.Select

    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="O:\1.To Quote\" & _
      FileName1, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Set WordApp = Nothing 'release the memory
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not possible, using the functionality built into Office applications, to combine content from different files into a single PDF. So, no, VBA can't do this, at least, not without a third-party library/software. (I do not know of one because I have no need for it.) And please note that asking about where to find such a library or software would be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up at least.